# Is there a shortcut for selecting word under cursor in Sublime Text, Atom

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, selection, sublimetext, atom-editor

Is there a shortcut or a command to select word under cursor in Sublime Text or Atom? I want a replacement for double-click. So I could press shortcut instead and get selection on a current word and start typing to replace it or get in quotes etc...

Answer (score 157, accepted):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on OSX

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on Windows/Linux

You can find all the default keybindings by going to `Preferences > Keybindings - Default` and perusing the list.

Comment: Inaddition to select a word. You can select the words enclosed in quotes with **SHIFT + CMD + SPACE** . It does more, check **Selection -> Expand selection to scope**

Comment: Great, I was under impression you have to select the word first for Cmd-D to work.

Answer (score 19):

You can add a key binding to select the word:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+w"], "command": "expand_selection", "args": {"to": "word"} }
```

Unlike the `find_under_expand` command (`control+d` by default) repeated presses won't add cursors at matching words.

Comment: Thanks for this! This was nagging me for years, that you don't always want `Ctrl+d` to select next word, but sometimes to just expand the selection to the whole word from its part.

Answer (score 10):

install [ExpandRegion](https://github.com/aronwoost/sublime-expand-region) if you want to expand the selection:

- Expand selection to word
- Expand selection to quotes (content only)
- Expand selection to quotes (with quotes)
- Expand selection to complete self closing tag
- Expand selection to parent node content
- Expand selection to complete node
- Expand selection to parent node content

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I looked around for this and eventually came up with this, which I assigned to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>

you need to paste it into a new user plugin python file

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class find_under_cursor(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        view = self.window.active_view()
        view.run_command("expand_selection", {"to": "word"}) 
        view.run_command("slurp_find_string")
        self.window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "find", "reverse": False} )
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  No need to sign your name, your name is already there on every post.

Answer (score 2):

### With Vim bindings (Vintage or vintageous)

`*` - to find next
`#` - to find last
For both, all matches are highlighted

### Without Vim bindings

For current file:  `CMD+E, CMD+F, Enter`
Explanation:
`CMD+E` - copies the word under cursor
`CMD+F` - bring up find in local file dialogue
`Enter` - er you know what this means

Substitute `CMD+F` for `CMD+SHIFT+F` to find in all files in project (or whatever search range you specify)